# Sending push notifications to specific users in the web

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

This might be more of a question towards push messages in general for the web, but I'm having trouble sending messages to users using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM).  The issue arises in the boundary case that there are multiple accounts or users on a single browser.  Generally, people don't share their phones, so this wouldn't be an issue for Android/iOS, and I think it's less common now, but people still do share their computers, either with their families or maybe at an internet cafe or something.

Currently, every time somebody who is logged in enables notifications, I add that push token for that device to an array in a database, then send a notification to all of those tokens when I send a push message to that user.  Although this is fine for mobile and most computers, what about shared computers?  Other users of that computer would keep getting notifications about things that are irrelevant to them.  If this is a family computer, I guess it's still alright, but what about at a web cafe if somebody uses it once then never again?  Would that not be incredibly irritating for everyone else?  Also, what if there are multiple different users on the same device that all use notifications?  Then, both users would get notifications for both users.  This is not good either.

I can't think of any way to circumvent this problem gracefully.  Maybe I can store the userID of the current logged in user in IndexedDB, replace it whenever a new user logs in instead, and only pop up the notifications if the userIDs match?  I could also add an "expiration date" so that the userID in IndexedDB times out after a while if the user doesn't log in for let's say 2 weeks.

Then again, it doesn't completely solve the problem either, it just makes it slightly less annoying, and also adds in other issues with multiples users with an account on the same device as well (ie: receiving the other person's notifications but not your own in certain scenarios).  Also, I would have to switch around my entire backend as well since I'm currently sending messages to FCM topics which users subscribe to, hence can't send specialized messages to certain tokens containing the user IDs.

I guess I could also use a "dirty fix" where I simply warn users that notifications are sent to the DEVICE, not the USER, and to be thoughtful when enabling this on shared computers.

Has anyone encountered (or thought of this problem) before and come up with a reasonable solution?  I would be very happy to have suggestions.  I think I'll go with the "dirty fix" for now, and might consider doing something else later if I can come up with a reasonable solution.  Of course, this is probably only an issue that affects ~1% of users at most anyway, so maybe I'm just thinking too much, and fixing this isn't worth the effort.

Comment: If you associate the token with a user, then when a user explicitly signs out you should delete their FCM token.